# Save log to a string

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I am debugging a webpage inside Unity that gets printed to a console. How do I copy the debug message into a string?

```
public string message; //print to this string

void SomeFunction(){
web.ExecuteJavaScript ("document.querySelector('iframe')).click();", s => Debug.Log (s));
}
```

Comment: `s => { Debug.Log (s); message = s; }`

Comment: Whilst using Unity can be fun, consider learning the basics of C# first.  It might be a bit daunting to learn both Unity and C# at the same time.  Good luck!  _Avoid fighting a war on two fronts it you don't need to._  Maybe make some awesome C# console games.  :)

Answer (score 3):

You just need to assign `s` to the target string:

```
public string message; //print to this string

void SomeFunction() {
   web.ExecuteJavaScript ("document.querySelector('iframe')).click();", s => {
      message = s;
      Debug.Log (s);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
public string message; //print to this string

void SomeFunction(){
    web.ExecuteJavaScript ("document.querySelector('iframe')).click();", 
    s => {
       Debug.Log (s);
       message = s; 
    });
}
```